# Why can i use self when I initialize property with a closure?

Tags: ios, swift

Official docs (Swift 4.1) says:

> If you use a closure to initialize a property, remember that the rest
>   of the instance has not yet been initialized at the point that the
>   closure is executed. This means that you cannot access any other
>   property values from within your closure, even if those properties
>   have default values. You also cannot use the implicit self property,
>   or call any of the instance’s methods.

So I guess i need to use lazy var,today I created a button

```
let loginRegisterButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 80, green: 101, blue: 161)
    button.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    button.addTarget(self , action: #selector(handleRegister), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()
```

so I just used self in addTarget method and XCode did not seem to bother even more program went without any errors. Everything worked out well.So Why can i use self when I initialize property with a closure? Is there some changes or maybe I missed something?

Comment: The target in your code is probably `nil`, the reason that this might work is that: _"...If you specify nil, UIKit searches the responder chain for an object that responds to the specified action message and delivers the message to that object"_ (from the documentation of the method)

Comment: I'm confused, your code is using `let`, but in your own question you're also talking about `lazy var`. so which one is it?

Comment: @Honey OP understands that `lazy var` is the proper way to solve the problem. The question is why the provided snippet works even though he doesn't use a `lazy var`.

Comment: @Honey I just did not use lazy var and used let

Comment: @Alladinian I was trying to be sure. How can it be `nil`? I mean a button is supposedly accessed on a viewController. The button can't exist without the viewController getting loaded...so how's this possible? or is that *during* initialization `self` is considered `nil`. I previously thought while it's _not_ `nil`...you just can't access it...

Comment: @N.Khasanov You can verify that the target is actually `nil` by setting a breakpoint during or after your controller's init and by inspecting the `_targetActions` array (in the debugger's variables view) of the button. In this example, `loginRegisterButton` is set _during_ the controller's initialization which means that there is no `self` yet (in other words you cannot guarantee that everything is initialized at this time). The way `lazy` solves this is that the actual assignment is deferred on first access.

Comment: @Alladinian  thank you very much!

Comment: @N.Khasanov You're welcome. I'll post an answer as well since you found my comments helpful.

Comment: It's actually more complicated than this. `self` doesn't evaluate to `nil` during execution of the closure; it evaluates to a function object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The target in your code is <strike>probably</strike> `nil`, the reason that this might work is that:

> ...If you specify nil, UIKit searches the responder chain for an
>   object that responds to the specified action message and delivers the
>   message to that object

(from the [documentation of the method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget))

You can verify that the target is actually `nil` by setting a breakpoint during or after your controller's init and by inspecting the `_targetActions` array (in the debugger's variables view) of the button (you can see that `target`'s address is `0x0`).

In your example, `loginRegisterButton` is set during the controller's initialization which means that there is no `self` yet (in other words you cannot guarantee that all instance variables are initialized at this point). The way `lazy` solves this is that the actual assignment is deferred on first access.

Answer (score 4):

Weirdly—perhaps buggily—the `self` in your closure evaluates to a function object. (Hamish explained in a comment that the function is a curried form of `NSObjectProtocol.self`.) However, when you later ask the button for its target, it reports `+[NSNull null]`:

```
let loginRegisterButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = .red
    button.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)

    print(self)
    // Output: (Function)

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRegister), for: .touchUpInside)

    let target = button.allTargets.first!.base
    print(target, type(of: target))
    // Output: <null> NSNull

    return button
}()
```

(Tested using Xcode 9.3.1.)

The function gets turned into `NSNull` as follows: the function object is allocated just before the call to `addTarget`, to be passed as the `target` argument. The `loginRegisterButton`-creating closure holds a strong reference to the newly-allocated function.

The button stores the target as a zeroing weak reference.

After `addTarget` returns, the closure releases its strong reference to the function. This was the only strong reference to the function, so Swift deallocates the function. This sets the button's weak reference to the function to nil.

When we then ask the button for `allTargets`, it constructs an `NSSet`. Since `NSSet` cannot hold nil directly, the button puts `+[NSNull null]` in the set instead.

Comment: That `self` is `NSObjectProtocol`'s [`self()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobjectprotocol/1418954-self) instance method, curried as `(Self) -> () -> Self` as Swift treats instance property initialisers as being in the static scope of the type (i.e you can directly refer to static members, [and get curried instance methods](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/)). If you did this in a class that didn't inherit from `NSObject`, you'd get an error about the use of `self`.

Comment: Interesting observation! Another thing regarding this is that if you do something like `let s = self`, the type inference system reports the type as `(MyViewController) -> () -> MyViewController`

Comment: aaand @Hamish has already clarified this while I was posting the comment...

Comment: I remember this giving an error on previous Swift versions. So what has changed now?

Comment: @robmayoff now i got what meant and understood your answer  thank you!