# Getting wrong default value

Tags: swift, initialization, default-value, getter-setter

I wrote a custom TableViewCell class that either returns the `accessibilityLabel` that was set on it, or just return its class name as the `accessibilityLabel`. Though one of the two implementations below doesn't work as expected. I'm trying to understand why...

returns **correct** className

```
class BaseTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var _acsLabel: String?

    override var accessibilityLabel: String?{
        get{
            return _acsLabel ?? "\(type(of: self))"
        }set (newValue) {
            _acsLabel = newValue ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

returns **incorrect** class name

```
class BaseTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var _acsLabel: String? = "\(type(of: self))"

    override var accessibilityLabel: String?{
        get{
            return _acsLabel
        }set (newValue) {
            _acsLabel = newValue ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

Both versions correctly return the value if I set the `accessibilityLabel`, however if the value is not set the default values they return are different.

For example I subclass `UserNameTableViewCell` off my `BaseTableViewCell` class and *don't* set the `accessibilityLabel` myself then:

- The correct version returns the `accessibilityLabel` as **UserNameTableViewCell**.
- The incorrect version returns the `accessibilityLabel` as returns **"(BaseTableViewCell) -> () -> BaseTableViewCell"**

Why is that?!

Comment: Your class names and the output you show do not match. Are these typos?

Comment: it was a typo. Thanks. Fixed

Comment: What is `UserNameTableViewCell`?

Comment: It's an example. So if I subclass `UserNameTableViewCell` off my `BaseTableViewCell` class and don't set the `accessibilityLabel` myself then I expect the `accessibilityLabel` to be **UserNameTableViewCell**. Yet it returns **"(BaseTableViewCell) -> () -> BaseTableViewCell"**. Is it clear now?

Comment: Probably because `self` hasn't been initialized yet at the point when the property default value is set. Making the property `lazy` should fix it.

Comment: Using `self` in a (non-lazy) property initialiser is usually a compiler error, but unfortunately isn't in your case because `NSObjectProtocol` has a `self()` instance method that you can refer to – compare my comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50393312/why-can-i-use-self-when-i-initialize-property-with-a-closure/50394741#comment87805830_50394741

Comment: @dan Hah! Good catch. That was it. Would you like to write that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is not initialized by the time you call it in the second version of the code, that is why it shows the name of the super class.

If you set that variable as `lazy`, it will not be set from the beginning, but will be set right when you do `myInstance.accesibilityLabel,` thus making sure the name of the class is already available because `self` would have been initialised.

Comment: It's not initialized by that time. ok. So what is it that I'm printing?

Comment: You are printing the `self()` of the `NSObjectProtocol`. `UITableViewCell` inherits from `UIView`, which implements `UICoordinateSpace`, which inherits from `NSObjectProtocol`. `UIView` implements `self()`. The default implementation of `self()`, like someone posted in a comment (did not see it before posting answer) is curried to `(Self) -> () -> (Self)`, which is what you get. And it is available before initialising because Swift lets you access property initialisers as if they were `static`.